# Not Getting the Root Name in JSON Format using WCF Rest

Tags: json, wcf, rest

I am not getting any root value of the Json Format.
I am getting the response as follows:

```
[{"Username":"demo","UserID":8,"Password":"demo","EmaiID":"demo@gmail.com"}]
```

I would like to have the format as follows

```
{UserList: [[{"Username":"demo","UserID":8,"Password":"demo","EmaiID":"demo@gmail.com"}]}
```

Service Declaration :

```
public interface IDemo
{  
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat =
    WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "/Validate", Method = "POST")]
    Stream ValidateUser(Login obj);

}

[DataContract]
public class Login
{

    public Login()
    {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Service Definition :

```
public class Demo: IDemo
{
    string Json = string.Empty;

    JavaScriptSerializer obj1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    public Stream ValidateUser(Login obj)
    {

        UserList objUserList = new UserList();
        Users objUser = new Users();
        objUser.Username = obj.Username;
        objUser.Password = obj.Password;

        objUserList = LoginDataService.ValidateUser(objUser.Username,objUser.Password) ;

        if (objUserList.Count > 0)
        {
            Json = obj1.Serialize(objUserList);
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType =  
            "application/json; charset=utf-8"; 
        }
        else
        {
            UserError objError = new UserError();

            objError.ErrMsg = "LoginFailed";objError.Username = objUser.Username ;

            Json = obj1.Serialize(objError);

            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = 
            "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json));  
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to get the result with root element and let me know what kind of mistake i have done.

Thanks & Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the format like that since you are serializing a collection into JSON. You can return a class that wraps the list inside as a property then you will get what you desire.

For ex. you can create a class like this

```
public class UserListResponse
{
   public UserList UserList{get; set;}
}
```

Now you get the JSON as what you expected, like

```
{UserList:[..]}
```

I don't understand why you are returning a Stream and doing yourself all the serialization framework, basically this all done by the framework. All you have to do is return the wrapper class `UserListResponse` from the service method.

```
public class Demo: IDemo
{
   public UserListResponse ValidateUser(Login obj)
   {
      ...
      return new UserListResponse{ UserList = objUserList};
   }
}
```

The WCF will take care of returning the structure into JSON or XML and you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: only thing to note here is return type match with method signature

Answer (score 0):

While the above solution perfectly works you can also try using paramter BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse of WebInvoke attribute on your method.

This wraps the values in type name.